# Theme.Translucent then show image after click

Tags: android, android-activity, transparency, viewflipper

I have completely lost my focus now.

I was trying to create a transparent background to show users phone screen like this.

https://market.android.com/details?id=net.kreci.crackedscreen&hl=en

Now i got it working. But i want to now add an image but it wont show till after the click.
Can this be done in Viewflipper with showing the activity Transclucent then showing image after the click? (cause i dont want the screen to flip to another activity, I want it to show straight away)

So technically if you don't understand what I meant.... Similar to the market link i added in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have knowledge regarding ViewFlipper class to implement in this situation,
But
I have one Idea to implement while creating two different activities to show 2 Images.

In `onCreate` of both activities write the below line right after `super.onCreate()`

`getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);`

This will set Window Animation to 0 so your screen will be changed *without any effects*.

Comment: yeh,I knew that but from your (bracket) line I got this idea. :)